# Internet slows down when visual studio running

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I have a weird problem on Windows 10 build 14295. I recently started playing around with Visual Studio and Xamarin. But I noticed after a while that when visual studio is running, internet on the computer slows down to a crawl. I've verified this multiple times. Run a video on youtube, start visual studio, video start buffering, wait for however long, close visual studio, video starts loading again. 
Does anyone have any idea what's going on here??

Comment: What Browser are you using?

Comment: Google chrome. Should also mention I've been having trouble getting the VS Emulator for Android to work. Don't know if that's related.